# match and replace content between brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to match and replace space in the content between opening "(-" and closing "-)" in javascript with double hypens "--"?

Example:

```
input: (-A room without books-) (-is like a body without a soul-)

output: (-A--room--without--books-) (-is--like--a--body--without--a--soul-)
```

Answer (score -1):

- To match exactly the space character, you can use the octal value <kbd>\040</kbd> [(Unicode characters displayed as octal)](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct)

example:

```js
"-A room without books-".replace(/\040/g, "--")
```